# React router server side not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-router

I have my app code here: https://github.com/WebTerminator/aldemar/commits/master

and I am trying to get my react app to work on the server side as well, at this stage it works partially.

The problem I have is: (sam problem happens on localhost)

if I navigate within the browser it all works fine, the moment I refresh this URL https://aldemar-productions.herokuapp.com/projects/margam2 I get a console error like:

> bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   [image]

If I refresh others URLs like "https://aldemar-productions.herokuapp.com/projects" or "https://aldemar-productions.herokuapp.com/about" they work fine.

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import routes from './src/client/app/config/routes.jsx';

let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
let app = express();

app.use(express.static('src/client/'));

// app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/client/index.html'))
// });

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match(
    { routes, location: req.url },
    (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {

      // in case of error display the error message
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }

      // in case of redirect propagate the redirect to the browser
      if (redirectLocation) {
        return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
      }

      // generate the React markup for the current route
      let markup;
      if (renderProps) {
        // if the current route matched we have renderProps
        markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
      } 
      // else {
      //   // otherwise we can render a 404 page
      //   markup = renderToString(<NotFoundPage/>);
      //   res.status(404);
      // }

      // render the index template with the embedded React markup
      return res.sendFile('index.html', {root : __dirname + '/src/client/'});
    }
  );
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server started');
```

routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Wrapper       from './../components/wrapper.jsx';
import Home          from './../components/home.jsx';
import Projects      from './../components/projects.jsx';
import SingleProject from './../components/projectContent/singleProject.jsx';
import About         from './../components/aboutUs.jsx'

if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('here baby');
    ReactDOM.render((
        <Router history={browserHistory} >
            <Route component={Wrapper} >
                <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="projects" component={Projects} />
                <Route path="projects/:id" component={SingleProject} />
                <Route path="about" component={About} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

singleProject.jsx (where I get the ID parameter from url to load the specific data)

```
import React from 'react';

import Video       from  './../video.jsx';
import Overview    from  './overview.jsx';
import Photography from  './photography.jsx';
import Details     from  './details.jsx';
import Cast        from  './cast.jsx';

import porgectsCollection from './../../data/projectInfo.js';

import { StickyContainer, Sticky } from 'react-sticky';

class Nav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mobileMenu: false
    };
  }
  showMobileMenu () {
    this.setState({ mobileMenu: !this.state.mobileMenu });
  }
  render () {
    let links = this.props.project.links.map(function(el, i){
      return <li key={i}>{el}</li>;
    });
    const open = this.state.mobileMenu ? ' open' : '';

    return (
      <Sticky stickyClassName="sticky-nav" topOffset={-100}>
        <span onClick={this.showMobileMenu.bind(this)} className="mobile-trigger">X</span>
        <nav className={"secondary-nav" + open}>
          <ul>
            {links}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </Sticky>
    );
  }
}

class SingleProject extends React.Component {
  getProjectDataFromUrl() {
    return **porgectsCollection.filter(el => el.title === this.props.params.id)**;
  }
  render () {
    let data = this.getProjectDataFromUrl(),
        project = data[0];
    return (
        <section className="project-page">
        <StickyContainer>
          <Video project={project} />
          <Nav project={project} />
          <Overview project={project} />
          <Photography project={project} />
          <Details project={project}  />
          <Cast project={project} />
        </StickyContainer>
        </section>
    );
  }
}

export default SingleProject;
```

When I hit a url like this "https://aldemar-productions.herokuapp.com/projects/margam2" I collect "margam2" as per my routes:

```
<Route path="projects/:id" component={SingleProject} />
```

and I load specific data based on that parameter. I believe the problem is around here with doing server side rendering.

**UPDATE-1**

adding this in the head of my index.html allows to get the content displayed when I refresh the page however the CSS is missing:

```
<base href="/" />
```

the css is fully accessible at http://localhost:8080/css/style.css, however when I refresh "http://localhost:8080/projects/margam2" the content is displayed but not the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after 2 days of research, this has helped me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    **<base href="/" />**
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/foundation.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

however I also found out this in my console:

*browser.js:49 Warning: Automatically setting basename using  is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. The semantics of  are subtly different from basename. Please pass the basename explicitly in the options to createHistory*

so need to find a solution for this.

**update-1**

even better solution I think. I have changed the assets path form relative to absolute:

see the **"/"** in front of every local asset

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your project's page, you are using an inline close div, like this:

`<div id="app" />`

In all your other pages, you are using a empty div

`<div id="app" > </div>`

**And that's the right way to do it.**

React-Router do not re-render your page, it only "re-add" your react code to your *id="app"*.
That's why when you open clicking it works and when you refresh it broke.